# How to query AWS ElasticSearch with SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

AWS documentation here indicates SQL querying is supported: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-elasticsearch-service-sql-support/

This page shows the syntax:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/sql-support.html

```
POST elasticsearch_domain/_opendistro/_sql
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM my-index LIMIT 50"
}
```

Running the following command in the Kibana Dev Tools

```
POST my_domain/_opendistro/_sql
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM my-index LIMIT 50"
}
```

Gives the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
        "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_opendistro]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
    "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_opendistro]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

My ElasticSearch version is 6.7.

Answer (score 1):

Since your elasticsearch is driven by AWS and you are using Kibana Dev tools, you could get your query results by following way

```
POST _opendistro/_sql
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM your_index "
}
```

You dont need to enter domain name. It worked for me.